# Git install with Aptana

Tags: eclipse, git, aptana, adt, egit

I use a variety of eclipse's for different uses, and for any backend work, my preference is Aptana, only problem with it, I feel is I think it's got a funky Git installation, which doesn't operate anything like EGit, which is common on the other versions I use.

The biggest irritation I have is comparison (with HEAD), and 'Show in history'.  I've attached screenshots to show what I mean (all against the same project and file, a git tracked 'MANIFEST.in' file),

'Compare with' in Aptana:

### [image: Compare with' in Aptana]

In Android Developer Tools:

### [image: In Android Developer Tools]

In Flash Builder:

### [image: In Flash Builder]

'Team' context view in Aptana:

### [image: 'Team' context view in Aptana]

In the others:

### [image: In the others]

I already have eGit installed,

### [image: I already have eGit installed]

Funky Aptana git plugin,

### [image: Funky Aptana git plugin]

Any notion as to how to get rid of (what I deem to be) the funky Aptana one, and instead use the proper, more functional and standard eGit one?

Comment: There's [an option which should disable Aptana's Git](http://tekkie.flashbit.net/developer-tools/eclipse/aptana/switching-from-aptanas-git-implementation-to-egit) in Preferences > Team > Git > Automatically attach our git support to projects added that have git repositories

Comment: My man, @cjc343, please put this as an answer, because it's 100% right!  I can't tell you how helpful this actually is to me, I'd tried a million overcomplicated approaches believing there wasn't possibly anything as simple as a ui button!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub><sup><sub><sup>Per request:</sup></sub></sup></sub>

There's [an option which should disable Aptana's Git](http://tekkie.flashbit.net/developer-tools/eclipse/aptana/switching-from-aptanas-git-implementation-to-egit) in `Preferences > Team > Git > Automatically attach our git support to projects added that have git repositories`